# RHEL5 - Install davfs from srpm - error with neon 0.30.0

Tags: patch, webdav, rpmbuild, rpm-spec, rhel5

I'm using an old RHEL5 system and trying to install davfs from source. I don't have the option of upgrading the entire system to a newer version, so I am stuck with what I have.

This is what I have tried so far:

- Setup rpmbuild environment following the instructions at https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SetupRpmBuildEnvironment. Works fine, I can use rpmbuild without needing sudo.
- Located the closest match for davfs srpm I could find for the system I am using: http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/26/dist/74/size/455789/name/davfs2-1.4.7-8.el6.src.rpm
- Downloaded and installed the srpm

  ```
  $ wget ftp://ftp.pbone.net/mirror/download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/fedora/epel/6/SRPMS/davfs2-1.4.7-8.el6.src.rpm
  $ rpm -i davfs2-1.4.7-8.el6.src.rpm
  ```
- Patched the source using included patch files

  ```
  $ cd ~/rpmbuild/SPECS
  $ rpmbuild -bp davfs2.spec
    Executing(%prep): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.fxF37X
    + umask 022
    + cd /home/myusername/rpmbuild/BUILD
    + LANG=C
    + export LANG
    + unset DISPLAY
    + cd /home/myusername/rpmbuild/BUILD
    + rm -rf davfs2-1.4.7
    + /usr/bin/gzip -dc /home/myusername/rpmbuild/SOURCES/davfs2-1.4.7.tar.gz
    + /bin/tar -xf -
    + STATUS=0
    + '[' 0 -ne 0 ']'
    + cd davfs2-1.4.7
    + /bin/chmod -Rf a+rX,u+w,g-w,o-w .
    + echo 'Patch #1 (davfs2-1.4.7-neon-0.30.patch):'
    Patch #1 (davfs2-1.4.7-neon-0.30.patch):
    + /bin/cat /home/myusername/rpmbuild/SOURCES/davfs2-1.4.7-neon-0.30.patch
    + /usr/bin/patch -p1
    patching file configure
    + echo 'Patch #2 (davfs2-1.4.7-system.patch):'
    Patch #2 (davfs2-1.4.7-system.patch):
    + /bin/cat /home/myusername/rpmbuild/SOURCES/davfs2-1.4.7-system.patch
    + /usr/bin/patch -p1
    patching file ChangeLog
    patching file src/kernel_interface.c
    patching file src/mount_davfs.c
    + exit 0
  ```
- Now when I try to build the patched source, I get the error below:

  ```
  $ rpmbuild -ba davfs2.spec
    ...
    configure: incompatible neon library version 0.30.0: wanted 0.25 26 27 28 29 30
    configure: error: could not find neon
    error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.AFBGNB (%build)
  ```
- I found a patchfile which indicates this has been fixed and it should build with neon 0.30.0: https://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/scm-commits/Week-of-Mon-20130916/1115037.html. These 2 lines from that page are interesting:

  ```
  # Add support for neon 0.30.0
  -%patch1
  ```

This is where I am stuck. I tried looking at the .patch files included under `~/rpmbuild/SOURCES/davfs2-1.4.7`, but couldn't figure out if the patch shown on 1115037.html was included in the srpm. If it was not, how do I update the patch and build it successfully?

I have tried installing davfs binary. It installs fine, but mount fails with SSL handshake error or SSL version mismatch error due to old SSL libraries. This is why I am trying to build from source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That line means take the `%patch1` line out of the specfile. But if you look lower in the patch, it re-adds it with the `-p1` parameter. That patch edits the first patch file and the specfile:

```
 davfs2-1.4.7-neon-0.30.patch |   47 ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++-----------
 davfs2.spec                  |    8 +------
```

So you need to try applying ALL the patches in that email.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up editing ./configure by hand and setting the flag that indicates correct neon version has been found - since I already have neon 0.30.0. Got past this point and able to mount the webdav share - ran into permission issues which I am sorting out now.

Comment: If all else fails, it's SELinux. ;)

Comment: Only if this was my home system :|